# Cosmos VGAScreen Clear Colors

Tags: colors, screen, vga, cosmos

I remember finding this online once but I can't seem to find it anywhere now. I'm creating an enumeration for each of the colors (ints) in the vgascreen.clear(int) method. Instead of testing out each number, I was looking for a description online for each number coresponding to it's correct integer value.

for example

```
VGAScreen.Clear(0); // Black Screen
VGAScreen.Clear(1); // Blue Screen
VGAScreen.Clear(2); // Green
...
...
```

As you can guess, testing out each number is getting to be tiresome and boring. Anybody know a link for what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First relevant image hit on google for [standard VGA palette](http://www.fountainware.com/EXPL/vga_color_palettes.htm) search.

[image: VGA palette]

Those are the colors set by **VGA BIOS** entering any 256 colors **VGA/VESA** video mode. It is designed for better dithering results ...

So it is high likelly you got the same colors.